# Apache camel: Break task into subtasks

Tags: apache-camel

I need to process 1000 files after downloading from ftp , the downloading part is done using apache camel, can I also break the processing of files into sub tasks using camel. like multiple processes that camel is handling for me

Comment: Sure what do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the `threads()` API to enable concurrent processing on a route...

```
from("file://downloaded").threads(10).to(...);
```

Comment: Thanks will try this